# How to restrict account creation by user accounts-password?

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-accounts

I'm working on an application where only the admin should be able to create users for the system; meaning the user is restricted from creating an account but can login if login credentials were made for him/her.

I'm thinking about using `houston:admin` to manually create users, but how can I restrict users from creating an account using `accounts-ui`?

Should I use different packages to achieve this altogether?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have several ways to prevent users from creating accounts:

1. throwing an error in the [Accounts.onCreateUser()](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/accounts_oncreateuser) callback (server only):

   ```
   Accounts.onCreateUser(function(options, user) {
     if (/* some logic to figure out if current user is an admin */) {
       return user;
     }
     throw new Meteor.Error("user creation disabled.");
   });
   ```

   This will prevent the account from being created if the current user is not an admin.
2. [configuring `Accounts`](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/accounts_config) to forbid account creation (both client and server):

   ```
   Accounts.config({
     forbidClientAccountCreation: true
   });
   ```

   which rejects calls to `createUser()` from the client (but will not prevent user creation using oAuth services).

A combination of both is a likely course of action.
Take a look at the linked documentation for more details.